# TensorFlow Serving REST API - JSON Parse Error

Tags: python, rest, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I've frozen and exported a `SavedModel`, which takes as input a batch of videos that has the following format according to `saved_model_cli`:

```py
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
inputs['ims_ph'] tensor_info:
    dtype: DT_UINT8
    shape: (1, 248, 224, 224, 3)
    name: Placeholder:0
inputs['samples_ph'] tensor_info:
    dtype: DT_FLOAT
    shape: (1, 173774, 2)
    name: Placeholder_1:0
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
... << OUTPUTS >> ......
Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

I have a TF-Serving (HTTP/REST) server successfully running locally. From my Python client code, I have 2 populated objects of type `numpy.ndarray`, named `ims` of shape (1, 248, 224, 224, 3) -- and `samples` of shape (1, 173774, 2).

I am trying to run an inference against my TF model server (see client code below) but am receiving the following error: `{u'error': u'JSON Parse error: Invalid value. at offset: 0'}`

```py
# I have tried the following combinations without success:
data = {"instances" : [{"ims_ph": ims.tolist()}, {"samples_ph": samples.tolist()} ]}
data = {"inputs" : { "ims_ph": ims, "samples_ph": samples} }

r = requests.post(url="http://localhost:9000/v1/models/multisensory:predict", data=data)
```

The [TF-Serving REST docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/api_rest) don't seem to indicate that any extra escaping / encoding is required here for these two input tensors. As these aren't binary data, I don't think base64 encoding is the right approach either. Any pointers to a working approach here would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should send your request like this, json serialize request body first.

```
r = requests.post(url="http://localhost:9000/v1/models/multisensory:predict", data=json.dumps(data))
```

Comment: It would've been helpful to understand why this is accepted solution i.e. some context.